# PostgreSQL text array - query as integer, ignoring non-digits

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table of people. Each person can have several regnums (mostly integers but some like M/2344 and W345). To make things a bit more complicated, there are NULLs, empties, and strings like 'NA'. Due to their unpredictable composition, the regnums are stored in a text array field (e.g. {12345,M/2344} and {3459,NA}).

Because *most* people have regnums that can be treated as integers, I would like to be able to do things with this field like find people with a regnum between, say, 491555 and 491685.

I've tried:

`SELECT id,forename,surname,regnum FROM (SELECT *, unnest(regnum) reg   FROM people) as TBL WHERE reg BETWEEN '491555' AND '491685';`

but results include out-of-range regnums, e.g. 49162. I assume this is because the unnested regnum field is still a text field(?)

I've also tried casting the regnum as an integer field - `unnest(regnum::integer[])` - but I get errors:
`Error in query: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "NA"`

I think I'm on the right track, but I don't get how to ignore non-int-like regnums. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if postgresql has this capability, but I would try setting a `CASE` as part of the select where the value of the column is tested if it is a number and: If yes, return the number, otherwise return a very big number (which would never be included in the range, or any other excluding value).

Comment: Thanks @FDavidov. I figured it would come to CASE, but I couldn't quite get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test if a text value consists only of digits by checking it with regular expression, like this:

```
SELECT '1234' ~ '^[0-9]+$' -- true
SELECT 'NA' ~ '^[0-9]+$' -- false
```

So, in your case you need to cast value to integer only if it is numerical:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN reg ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN reg::integer ELSE null END) BETWEEN 491555 AND 491685
```

Comment: Perfect! I literally copy/pasted and it worked a treat. Thanks @pumbo.